# aliasing command options

Tags: bash, alias, options

Is there any way to alias the options of a command?  For instance, I often use the options `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` with `find`, but these are quite long at 9 characters apiece, and don't have corresponding short forms. I would like to alias them to something faster to type like `-mn` and `-mx`.  Of course, one can always build a custom binary with new option names, but I am interested in shell built-ins/utilities that provide this behavior (analogously to how `alias` allows commands to be aliased).

Comment: A function wrapper that parses options (carefully), I suppose. Though I'd warn you away from this, just like I don't rely on `alias rm="rm -i".

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell function or script. The only issue is how much you care about corner cases. If you don't care at all then

```
 #!/bin/bash
 args=()
 while (($# > 0))
 do
      case "$1" in
      ("-mn") args=("${args[@]}" "-mindepth") ;;
      ("-mx") args=("${args[@]}" "-maxdepth") ;;
      (*) args=("${args[@]}" "$1") ;;
      esac
      shift
 done
 exec find "${args[@]}"
```

If you care a little more then use

```
      ("-mn") args=("${args[@]}" "-mindepth" "$2") ; shift ;;
```

and add similar cases for all the other find options which take a parameter so you don't convert

```
  find / -name -mn -print
```

into

```
  find / -name -mindepth -print
```

Don't call this script `find`, perhaps `fnd` as it takes shorter options than find, or `myfind`. It is possible to make it work if you call it find, but as mentioned in the comments you don't what to alter the behavior of standard programs.

Comment: To append to an array, you can use `args+=('-mindepth')`.